# Reusing a directive template for multiple forms with isolated scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-template

I'm working on a project where the user needs to be able to create many instances of the same form. As of now the user can click a button to create one or more forms.  The problem I'm having is that by isolating the scope, as I think I should be doing given that I'm reusing the same directive, my `ng-models` can't communicate with the parent controller.

My directive for `<rule-form></rule-form>`..

```
(function(){
'use strict';

var ruleForm = function(){
    return{
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: {},
        templateUrl: 'edit/rule-create/ruleForm.html',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){
            scope.length = document.forms.length;   
        }
    }
}

angular.module('ganeshaApp')
.directive('ruleForm', ruleForm)
})();
```

And my template...

```
<form class="edit__div--rule-form" name="form_{{length}}">
<input type="text" placeholder="Rule Title" ng-model="rcCtrl.ruleTitle">
<div class="edit__div--rc-toolbar">
    <select class="edit__btn--rc-select" ng-model="rcCtrl.select" apply-statement-type>
        <option value="obligation statement">obligation statement</option>
        <option value="prohibition statement">prohibition statement</option>
        <option value="permission statement">restricted permission statement</option>
    </select>
    <div class="edit__btn--rc-noun">
        Add noun/verb
    </div>
    <div class="edit__btn--rc-save" ng-click="rcCtrl.saveRule()">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-saved"></span>Save
    </div>
    <div class="edit__btn--rc-cancel">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
        Cancel
    </div>
</div>
<div class="edit__select--statement-type"></div>

<div ng-show="rcCtrl.showTextEdit" class="edit__div--rule-form-text" contenteditable="true" ng-model="rcCtrl.ruleText"></div>
```

I tried using `$parent` , (e.g. `$parent.rcCtrl.ruleText`), but then I'm back to the problem of not having isolated scopes and each form updates the others.  I'm a bit confused about this really.  Does anyone know a solution to this problem, or is it just a problem with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a controller to your directive.

```
angular.module('ganeshaApp').directive('ruleForm', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: {},
        templateUrl: 'edit/rule-create/ruleForm.html',
        controller: "rulesFormController as rcCtrl",
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){
            scope.length = document.forms.length;   
        }
    }
});
```

The AngularJS `$compile` service will then create an instance of the controller for each instance of the directive and attach it to each isolate scope.

For more information, see the [AngularJS Comprehensive Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#comprehensive-directive-api).

Comment: Thanks, George.  That's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: You're welcome. For more information, see the [AngularJS Comprehensive Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#comprehensive-directive-api).